# Как правильно изменить поле класса?

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.x, классы

Как в данном коде изменить переменные `a, b, c` класса `Class1`, чтобы вывод был таким: `0, 1, 2`

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = -1
        self.b = -1
        self.c = -1

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [Class1()] * 5

    def change(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.x[i].a = i
            self.x[i].b = i
            self.x[i].c = i
```

Сейчас выводит `-1, -1, -1`

```
class2 = Class2()
print(class2.x[1].a)
print(class2.x[2].c)
print(class2.x[3].b)
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Create List of Single Item Repeated n Times in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3459098/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А Вы же метод change не вызываете. Но даже этого мало, будут выводиться четверки, если его вызвать. А все потому, что вы создав экземпляр класса1 умножили его на 5, создав 5 ссылок на один объект, а не пять новых экземпляров.

Закомментировал строчку создания 5 новых класс1 и написал новую, плюс добавил пару принтов для наглядности. Попробуйте их комментировать по очереди, и смотрите на выводимые id объектов. Должен признать, неплохая задачка вышла для собеседования, без запуска не разобрался бы :)

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = -1
        self.b = -1
        self.c = -1


class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        #self.x = [Class1()] * 5
        self.x = [Class1() for _ in range(5)]


    def change(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.x[i].a = i
            self.x[i].b = i
            self.x[i].c = i
            print(self.x[i])

class2 = Class2()
class2.change()

for i in range(5):
    print(class2.x[i])

print(class2.x[1].a)
print(class2.x[2].c)
print(class2.x[3].b)
```

Comment: да, спасибо, теперь понятно. В моем случае это просто недопонимание основ, т. к. пришлось переключиться на незнакомый язык.

Comment: Ок, на здоровье. Это бывает, момент неочевидный слегка, да.

Comment: @jfs да, точно, спасиб.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем такие велосипеды? Вы слышали про наследование?

```
class Class1(object):
    a = -1


class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
```